# Установка поддомена в Cloudflare

Tags: dns, cloudflare

столкнулся с DDOS атакой посоветовали установить Cloudflare. У мене есть мой домен и куча поддоменов как установить защиту Cloudflare на один из поддоменов?
[image: Скрин]

Comment: Надо кликнуть по облаку. Оранжевое облако - защита (и кеширование) включены. Серое - выключены.

Comment: Как подключить поддомен? Сначала DNS ? Обьясните пожалуйста

Comment: http://take.ms/QMR4b

Comment: @KAGGDesign после этого действия ClaudFlare будет установлен? И защита тоже? Извините, за возможно глупые вопросы! Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Ну он у вас уже есть. Показанным на картинке действием вы добавляете поддомен. Он будет указывать на тот же IP, что имеет основной домен. Оранжевое облако включит кеш и защиту от DDOS (которая отличается в зависимости от уровня аккаунта).

Comment: @KAGGDesign спасибо огромное!

Comment: @KAGG Design Возле поля, у Вас это "test-xxx", ошибка Invalid hostname: Use '@' to represent the root domain.

Comment: Не надо сказок. Только что создал такой поддомен: http://take.ms/nBEAI Вы CNAME выбрали, или не смотрите на картинку?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84637/discussion-between-kagg-design-and-alexander).